# Changing the value of a variable with pointers not working

Tags: c

Basically I have a function called MinSubTab that is supposed to calculate the sum of the array passed and also to change the value passed in the first argument from inside the function without using return. This is done with pointers. Anyway, I think it'd be easier if I just showed you the code so here it is:

*maintab.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "tab.h"

int main(){
    int *reftab;
    int min;
    reftab = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * NMAX);
    InitTab(reftab,NMAX);
    printf("\n Total: %d et min: %d", MinSumTab(&min, reftab, NMAX), min);
    free(reftab);
    return 0;
}
```

*tab.c*

```
void InitTab(int *tab, int size){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        *(tab+i) = rand() % 10;
    }
}
int MinSumTab(int *min, int *tab, int size){
    int total=0;
    int minimum = NMAX;
    int temp = *min;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        total += *(tab+i);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        if(*(tab+i)<minimum){
            minimum = *(tab+i);
        }
    }
    *min = minimum;
    return total;
}
```

So the expected result here is that the sum is printed (which it is) and the minimum value of the array is printed (which it is not). Every single time the min variable equals 8 and I've no idea how to actually change the value of min from within that function.

Please help as my brain has no more capacity for rational thought, it's been 1.5 hrs and no solution in sight. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is in this line `printf("\n Total: %d et min: %d", MinSumTab(&min, reftab, NMAX), min);` I'm not sure at all, but I think that the parameter `min` is evaluated before the function execution, so you're printing an uninitialized value (your `8`!). Try to store the result of the function in a variable and then print them using printf.

Comment: I executed it on my Android and it works! Probably it is an implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: As @gior91 says, the order of evaluation of the arguments to a function call is unspecified.  It is therefore unsafe in your case to rely on `MinSubTab` to update the value of `min` before it is evaluated for use in `printf()`.  Resolve this simply by being a little less clever: run `MinSubTab()` separately, first, capturing its return value in a variable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger as I suspected! Thank you for your confirmation!

Comment: tip: it helps if you include separate 'expected output' and 'obtained output' sections in your question, for clarity.

Comment: @gior91 and everyone else, thank you guys so much. That's exactly what it was. It's been a couple years since I used C and it's all a big headache when you don't practice it. Thanks for saving me another headache today.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a small mistake:

You initialize `minimum` with `NMAX`, which I assume is 8 (the size of the array). 99.9% of the random numbers will be bigger. So 8 is chosen as the minimum.

What you really want is to initialize it with `RAND_MAX` – the maximum value `rand()` can return.

Answer (score 0):

In C order of evaluation and argument passing is undefined.

You can of course the order yourself but it only to feed your curiosity.

```
#include <stdio.h>

volatile char *message[] = {
    "fisrt", "second", "third", "fourth"
};

int print(size_t x)
{
    printf("%s\n", message[x]);
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", print(0), print(1), print(2), print(3));

    return 0;
}
```

Note. There is one exception from this rule.

Logical operators are evaluated form the left to the right.

`if( x != NULL && *x == 5)`is safe because x will not be dereferenced if it is NULL